# Android Spinner drop down textcolor of selected different from the list items text color

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner drop down list that I'd like to change color of selected item but not the list item.

[image: Look at this picture]

What I want is to make the selected item text color in the blue background only to be white and the others to be black as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private OnItemSelectedListener OnCatSpinnerCL = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {

        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(5);



    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks it helped alot instead of a slight flicker while changing the font color. Do you have any idea?